# R shiny ggplot - How not to let the year labels go beyond the grid?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, scale

My friend and I are learning R shiny with ggplot. We've found that the x-axis labels go beyond the grid.

The simple data file is here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pZQe89wxw14lirW2mRIgi9h29yPyc7Fs/view?usp=sharing

We removed the decimal points for year in slidebar, and in x-axis (using `scale_x_discrete(limits=c(input$year[1]:input$year[2]))`)

But another problem arises: Why does the 2020 x-axis label go beyond the grid?

PS: There are no data for all items in 2020 and 2021.

There are two ways to solve: 1. cover the x-axis labels in the grid. 2. disallow users to select years without data along the slidebar.

May I know how to writes codes for both ways?

Here is the source code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(reshape)
library(scales)



ecd <- read.csv("ecd-figures.csv")

c(
  "No of case" = "no_of_case",
  "Minor Case" = "minor_case",
  "All Non Fatal Case" = "all_non_fatal_case",
  "Fatal Case" = "fatal_case"
) -> vec

ui <- fluidPage(sidebarLayout(
  sidebarPanel
  (
    checkboxGroupInput("feature",
                       "Feature",
                       vec),
    sliderInput(
      "year",
      "Year",
      min = 2015,
      max = 2021,
      value = c(2015, 2021),
      sep = "",
      step = 1
    )
  ),
  
  mainPanel(tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("Plot", plotOutput("correlation_plot")),
    tabPanel("Table", tableOutput("ecd"))
  ))
))



server <- function(input, output) {
  yearrange <- reactive({
    ecd %>% subset(year %in% input$year[1]:input$year[2]) %>% select(c(year, input$feature))
  })
  
  output$correlation_plot <- renderPlot({
    
    ecdsubset <- yearrange()
    ecdsubset <- melt(ecdsubset, id = "year")
    validate(need(input$feature, 'Check at least one item.'))
    ggplot(ecdsubset,aes(x=year,y=value,color=variable))+geom_line(size=1)+
      scale_x_discrete(limits=c(input$year[1]:input$year[2]))
    
  })
  output$ecd <- renderTable({
    yearrange()
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Here is the output.

[image]

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For 1) Remove `scale_x_discrete`.

For 2) Instead of hardcoding `min`, `max` and `value` you can get those values from the data.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(reshape)
library(scales)


ecd <- read.csv("ecd-figures.csv")

c(
  "No of case" = "no_of_case",
  "Minor Case" = "minor_case",
  "All Non Fatal Case" = "all_non_fatal_case",
  "Fatal Case" = "fatal_case"
) -> vec

ui <- fluidPage(sidebarLayout(
  sidebarPanel
  (
    checkboxGroupInput("feature",
                       "Feature",
                       vec),
    sliderInput(
      "year",
      "Year",
      min = min(ecd$year),
      max = max(ecd$year),
      value = range(ecd$year),
      sep = "",
      step = 1
    )
  ),
  
  mainPanel(tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("Plot", plotOutput("correlation_plot")),
    tabPanel("Table", tableOutput("ecd"))
  ))
))



server <- function(input, output) {
  yearrange <- reactive({
    ecd %>% subset(year %in% input$year[1]:input$year[2]) %>% select(c(year, input$feature))
  })
  
  output$correlation_plot <- renderPlot({
    
    ecdsubset <- yearrange()
    ecdsubset <- melt(ecdsubset, id = "year")
    validate(need(input$feature, 'Check at least one item.'))
    ggplot(ecdsubset,aes(x=year,y=value,color=variable))+geom_line(size=1)
    
  })
  output$ecd <- renderTable({
    yearrange()
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: for 1), the problem is, if I use ````scale_x_continuous````, decimal points will reappear..... For example, 2015.00, 2015.25, 2015.50, 2015.75, 2016.00. Non-sensical.

Comment: I don't get decimals using my code. Maybe you want to change `year` to factors ?

Comment: should it be this?

 ````validate(need(input$feature, 'Check at least one item.'))
    ecd$year <- as.factor(ecd$year)
    ggplot(ecdsubset,aes(x=year,y=value,color=variable))+geom_line(size=1)+
      scale_x_continuous(limits=c(input$year[1]:input$year[2]))````

It failed.....

Comment: I have updated the answer and added an image to show the plot looks at my end.

Comment: Um.....but once I select a narrower range, say 2016 to 2017, the year labels are in decimal form, as shown here : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MleXuwpQPAcNiBuNpFCxg3Bi23milYy2/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to Ronak Shah's answer put this code to the server part in `yeararrange`

```
 mutate(across(where(is.numeric), as.integer)) %>%
```

full code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(reshape)
library(scales)

ecd <- read.csv("ecd-figures.csv")

c(
    "No of case" = "no_of_case",
    "Minor Case" = "minor_case",
    "All Non Fatal Case" = "all_non_fatal_case",
    "Fatal Case" = "fatal_case"
) -> vec

ui <- fluidPage(sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel
    (
        checkboxGroupInput("feature",
                           "Feature",
                           vec),
        sliderInput(
            "year",
            "Year",
            min = min(ecd$year),
            max = max(ecd$year),
            range = c(min(ecd$year), max(ecd$year)),
            sep="",
            step = 1
        )
    ),
    
    mainPanel(tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Plot", plotOutput("correlation_plot")),
        tabPanel("Table", tableOutput("ecd"))
    ))
))



server <- function(input, output) {
    yearrange <- reactive({
        ecd %>% 
            mutate(across(where(is.numeric), as.integer)) %>% 
            subset(year %in% input$year[1]:input$year[2]) %>% 
            select(c(year, input$feature))
    })
    
    output$correlation_plot <- renderPlot({
        
        ecdsubset <- yearrange()
        ecdsubset <- melt(ecdsubset, id = "year")
        validate(need(input$feature, 'Check at least one item.'))
        ggplot(ecdsubset,aes(x=year,y=value,color=variable))+geom_line(size=1)+
            theme(legend.position = "none") +
            scale_x_discrete(limits=c(input$year[1]:input$year[2]))
        
    })
    output$ecd <- renderTable({
        yearrange()
    })
    
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you first. Your advice will work as long as ````scale_x_discrete```` is used. But as Ronak Shah mentions that I should better use ````scale_x_continuous````. And because of this, the decimals are still here...... https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MleXuwpQPAcNiBuNpFCxg3Bi23milYy2/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

I finally adopt Joshua Cook's solution, i.e. writing an extra function for label breaks. Full code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(reshape)
library(scales)



ecd <- read.csv("ecd-figures.csv")

c(
  "No of case" = "no_of_case",
  "Minor Case" = "minor_case",
  "All Non Fatal Case" = "all_non_fatal_case",
  "Fatal Case" = "fatal_case"
) -> vec

ui <- fluidPage(sidebarLayout(
  sidebarPanel
  (
    checkboxGroupInput("feature",
                       "Feature",
                       vec),
    sliderInput(
      "year",
      "Year",
      min = min(ecd$year),
      max = max(ecd$year),
      value = range(ecd$year),
      sep = "",
      step = 1
    )
  ),
  
  mainPanel(tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("Plot", plotOutput("correlation_plot")),
    tabPanel("Table", tableOutput("ecd"))
  ))
))



server <- function(input, output) {
  yearrange <- reactive({
    ecd %>%
      subset(year %in% input$year[1]:input$year[2]) %>%
      select(c(year, input$feature))
  })
  
  integer_breaks <- function(n = 5, ...) {
    fxn <- function(a) {
      breaks <- floor(pretty(a, n, ...))
      names(breaks) <- attr(breaks, "labels")
      breaks
    }
    return(fxn)
  }
  
  
  output$correlation_plot <- renderPlot({
    ecdsubset <- yearrange()
    ecdsubset <- melt(ecdsubset, id = "year")
    validate(need(input$feature, 'Check at least one item.'))
    ggplot(ecdsubset, aes(x = year, y = value, color = variable)) + geom_line(size = 1) + scale_x_continuous(breaks = integer_breaks())
    
    
  })
  output$ecd <- renderTable({
    yearrange()
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

What I don't understand is, what is the meaning of `...` in `integer_breaks <- function(n = 5, ...)` ? Thanks for your advice.

[image]